# How to structure use of classes inside classes so that circular references are avoided?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following engine class which uses two renderer classes that extend a base renderer class:

```
import {RendererOne} from "./renderer-one";
import {RendererTwo} from "./renderer-two";

export class engine {

    coordinates: number;
    randomPropery: string;

    produceRenderer (type, params) {

        switch type {
            case "map":
                return new RendererOne(this, params)
            case "other":
                return new RendererTwo(this, params)
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }
}
```

The BaseRenderer class is defined as follows:

```
import { engine} from "./index";


export abstract class BaseRenderer {

    engine: engine;

     constructor(engine: engine, params?) {

         this.engine = engine;

     }

     //various drawing methods defined here which are common to all renderers

    attach () {

        const engine = this.engine;

        //use engine defined methods and engine properties inside here

    }

}
```

And here is a rough example of one of the renderers which extend the baseRenderer:

```
import {BaseRenderer} from "./base-renderer";
import { engine } from "./index";

export class RendererOne extends BaseRenderer {

    madeUpProperty: string;
    params: any;

    constructor(engine: engine, params?) {
        super(engine, params);
        var derivedParams = this.params;
    }


}
```

The above causes a circular reference, so what is the correct way to structure code similar to the above?

The Renderers need access to the engine object properties and it's methods. This is trimmed down toy code so please excuse any rough typos - hopefully it conveys the problem I am faced with.

Answer (score 0):

You should look the Factory design pattern, I think it might help you, you would have a class RendererFactory that is in charge to determine which type of renderer it should create.

Edit: So that your engine won't have to import both class but only the Factory

Edit#2: Also, since you pass the engine in the constructor of your Renderer classes, why import it ?